# get text between brackets which can be repeated

Tags: php

I would like to find all values in brackets that are in the `$text` below  and replace with the right value from an array of `$data`:

```
1) $text = "My name is {NAME} {SURNAME} and I have {NUMBER} dogs";
2) $text = "My name is {NAME}. I have {COLOR} car.";
```

The thing is that I don't know how many are there (example shows 3 or 2, but it can be 4 or 6 or more).

```
$data["name"] = "John";
$data["surname"] = "Smith";
$data["number"] = 2;
$data["color"] = red;
```

and so on...

What would be the simplest way of doing this? I'm using `str_replace()` but the hard thing for me is to find values in the brackets.

```
function findAndReplace($text, $data) {

  return $newText;
}
```

Comment: How about a `preg_replace()` with a custom callback....

Comment: Well thats not difficult, why not have a go yourself

Answer (score 4):

[`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is ideal for this job.

Try to understand what this code does and don't just blindly copy-paste it :)

<sup><sub>(Note that the keys are always lowercased (*{NAME}* vs *$data["name"]* in your examples).</sub></sup>

```
function findAndReplace($text, array $data)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\{(\w++)\\}/', function ($match) use ($data) {
        $key = mb_strtolower($match[1]);

        if (isset($data[$key])) {
            return $data[$key];
        }
    }, $text);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$text = "My name is {NAME} {SURNAME} and I have {NUMBER} dogs";

$data["name"] = "John";
$data["surname"] = "Smith";
$data["number"] = 2;
$data["color"] = "red";

var_dump(
    findAndReplace($text, $data)
);
```

**Output:**

> string(39) "My name is John Smith and I have 2 dogs"

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$text = "My name is {name} {surname} and I have {number} dogs";
$data["name"] = "John";
$data["surname"] = "Smith";
$data["number"] = 2;
$data["color"] = "red";
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $key="{".$key."}";
    $text=str_replace($key,$value,$text);
}
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: I think this one is the simplest method. I'm wondering why I couldn't think of this before, it's so simple to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your array keys can have the same names as the patterns you need to change, then you can do this:

```
$data["{NAME}"] = "John";
$data["{SURNAME}"] = "Smith";
$data["{NUMBER}"] = 2;
$data["{COLOR}"] = red;

$result = str_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $text);
```

Otherwise you could do with lowercasing your patterns in the string and removing the brackets then:

```
$result = str_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using the simplest `str_replace()` function and a foreach loop.

```
function findAndReplace($text, $data)
{
    foreach ( $data as $name => $val) {
        $t = sprintf('{%s}',strtoupper($name));
        $text = str_replace($t, $val, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}



$text = "My name is {NAME} {SURNAME} and I have {NUMBER} dogs";


$data["name"] = "John";
$data["surname"] = "Smith";
$data["number"] = 2;
$data["color"] = "red";

$text = "My name is {NAME} {SURNAME} and I have {NUMBER} dogs";
echo findAndReplace($text, $data) . PHP_EOL;

$text = "My name is {NAME}. I have {COLOR} car.";
echo findAndReplace($text, $data);
```

The Result:

```
My name is John Smith and I have 2 dogs
My name is John. I have red car.
```